# How do I associate test methods to azure test plan test cases without using visual studio?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, xunit

I have an xunit solution which contains my test methods.
I know how we can associate an azure test plan test case with automation test method using visual studio from visual studio test explorer window.

But I want to achieve this without using visual studio.

I am using xunit C#.

If you know please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: @DanielMann I was looking for anyway if it was possible but could not find anything on the internet and also I looked at MS docs but there was nothing there which would help me. So I have raised a feature suggestion in MS developer community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1131118/associate-test-methods-to-azure-test-plan-test-cas.html

Answer (score 0):

> How do I associate test methods to azure test plan test cases without using visual studio?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is by designed and Visual Studio is the only one that provides this feature at present.

According to [the blog](https://www.deliveron.com/blog/test-case-association-xunit-nunit-and-mstestv2-tests-available-visual-studio-2017-1571/) and the Official document [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops), starting from Visual Studio `2017 15.7.1`, we could use **Visual Studio** to associate automated tests with a test case:

> Consider using **Visual Studio** to associate automated tests with a test
> case when:
>
> You created a manual test case that you later decide is a good test to
> automate, but you still want to be able to run that test as part of a
> test plan.
>
> You want to enable end-to-end traceability of requirements. If your
> test cases are linked to requirements or user stories, the results of
> the test execution can be used to establish the quality of those
> requirements.

Besides, the Product team does not give priority to adding support for other methods at present.

Comment: I know the way it works with visual studio. I wish if there was a way to do it using some CLI based tool or something

Comment: @PankajDevrani, Sorry about that. Just like I said in the answer, Visual Studio is the only one that provides this feature at present. I am afraid we could not do this by using CLI based tool or something. You could submit this request to the product team: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21